# find onelogin login url

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

I want to implement onelogin concpet.

I have application **APP-A1** and it holds a link of another application *APP-A2*

When user has logged in my app **APP-A1**, when user click on link of APP-A2*

It should not ask for login again.

I found below url

https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/c-and-aspnet

I assume When user click on link of **APP-A2**  the below code should run and and redirect to *idp_sso_target_url*

```
using OneLogin.Saml;

  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          AccountSettings accountSettings = new AccountSettings();

          OneLogin.Saml.AuthRequest req = new AuthRequest(new AppSettings(), 
          accountSettings);

          Response.Redirect(accountSettings.idp_sso_target_url + "?SAMLRequest=" +
              Server.UrlEncode(req.GetRequest(AuthRequest.AuthRequestFormat.Base64)));
      }
  }




public class AccountSettings
{
    public string certificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIBrTCCAaGgAwIBAgIBATADBg
    EAMGcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDAQQIDApD\nYWxpZm9ybmlhMRUwEwYDVQQHDAxTYW50YSBNb25pY2Ex
    ETAPBgNVBAoMCE9uZUxv\nZ2luMRkwFwYDVQQDDBBhcHAub25lbG9naW4uY29tMB4XDTEwMDMwOTA5NTgzNF
    oX\nDTE1MDMwATA5NTgzNFowZzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgMCkNhbGlmb3Ju\naWExFTATBgNVBA
    cMDFNhbnRhIE1vbmljYTERMA8GA1UECgwIT25lTG9naW4xGTAX\nBgNVBAMMEGFwcC5vbmVsA2dpbi5Ab20w
    gZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJ\nAoGBANtmwriqGBbZy5Dwy2CmJEtHEENVPoATCZP3UDESRDQmXy
    9Q0Kq1lBt+KyV4\nkJNHYAAQ9egLGWQ8/1atkPBye5s9fxROtf8VO3uk/x/X5VSROEIrhFISGmKUnVXa\nUh
    LFIXkGSCAIVfoR5S2ggdfpINKUWGsWS/lEzLNYMBkURXuVAgMBAAEwAwYBAAMB\nAA==\n-----END CERTI
    FICATE-----";

    public string idp_sso_target_url = "https://app.onelogin.com/saml/signon/12345";
}
```

Below code base should be there on **APP-A2** page to authenticate the incoming response and allow user to login the application.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // replace with an instance of the users account.
        AccountSettings accountSettings = new AccountSettings();

        OneLogin.Saml.Response samlResponse = new Response(accountSettings);
        samlResponse.LoadXmlFromBase64(Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]);

        if (samlResponse.IsValid())
        {
            Response.Write("OK!");
            Response.Write(samlResponse.GetNameID());
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

If my assumption is correct where should I get the URL in developer account,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At SAML there are 2 actors:
 - Identity Providers. Where the users are authenticated.
 - Service Providers. Protect the apps and redirect to the IdP when user want to log in the app.

In your case, you need to add SAML support to APP-A1 and APP-A2 (turning them Service Providers) and connect both to an Identity Provider.

Service Peoviders need to send an AuthNRequest (first code you mentioned) to the IdP SSO URL.

And also need to have an Assertion Consumer Service (SP ACS URL, second code you mentioned) in order to receive and process the SAMLResponse.

If you are using Onelogin as Identity Provider and have a a developer account you will be able to go to Apps>Add app and later look for a "SAML Test Connector"

On the "Configuration" section you should provide SP info and at the SSO section you get the IdP data... you may create one App connector per each SP. More info at
https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673944-How-to-Use-the-OneLogin-SAML-Test-Connector

IMPORTANT: The dotnet toolkit  is a proof of concept, you should not use it in production as mentioned on the description of its github repository:
https://github.com/onelogin/dotnet-saml
Please use the alternatives mentioned there.